# Plugin error message on startup QGIS 3.16.7-Hannover

Tags: qgis

Can anyone tell me what this means? Have tried fresh reinstalls and removing all plugins.

> 2021-06-03T08:34:45     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 112, in loadAlgorithms
> folder = ScriptUtils.resetScriptFolder(folder)
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 114, in resetScriptFolder
> commonSettingPath = os.path.join(paths[appIndex], paths[profileIndex])
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: One of the two arrays is shorter than the index variable.

Comment: Have you tried creating a completely new profile? That usually helps in this kind of situations. All the plugins are connected to your profile and depending on how they do the uninstalling process they might cause this kind of problems. You can create a new profile in Settings --> User Profiles --> New Profile.

Comment: I resolve this problem, renaming the Profile folder -> default (C:\Users[Your_User_Windows_Nmae]\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default) with the name default_old.
When you start again Qgis, the folder is created again, and the problem desapears.
You must reinstall your plugins (and perhpas you discover that a plugin is not working well).